# How to see if azure batch job exists from azure cli?

Tags: azure-cli, azure-batch

Currently I do the following to see if a job exists:

```
id=$(az batch job show \
    --job-id $1 \
    --query id \
    --output tsv \
    --account-key $AZ_BATCH_KEY \
    --account-name $AZ_BATCH_ACCOUNT \
    --account-endpoint $AZ_BATCH_ENDPOINT)

if [ "$id" == "" ]; then
    # create job
else
    # enable job
fi
```

Is there a more robust way to do this?

Basically, I want to check if a job already exists. If it does, I want to enable it and add tasks to it. Otherwise, I will create it and add tasks.

I am using the auto pool feature to create a pool on job creation and delete the pool on job termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above looks fine to me, seems like another one possible way could be like this:

Get list of the jobs and then you have a collection to parse, or filter.

```
az batch job list [--account-endpoint]
              [--account-key]
              [--account-name]
              [--expand]
              [--filter]
              [--job-schedule-id]
              [--select]
```

with regards to `filter` these links might be helpful:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-cli-get-started#efficient-queries-for-batch-resources

Doc link:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/batch/job?view=azure-cli-latest#az-batch-job-list

With regards to robustness, I am not sure if there is any performance metrics around the specific commands. Might be worth to share the scenario for the performance optimization if that's at all in play here.